# Переменные в Javascript

Tags: javascript

Всем привет, у меня два вопроса по JS.

1. Что вернёт мне вот такая запись: `document.body.style.opacity`? Строку или дробное число?
2. Как в Javascript преобразовать один тип в другой? Какая форма записи?

Спасибо.

Проэксперементировал, alert(document.body.style.opacity); выдаёт undefined. Вопрос почему? ведь в css стиле opacity задано.

Answer (score 1):

1. document.body.style как правило подразумевает строку. (а почему бы вам самим не поэксперементировать?)
2. Тип(переменная) (alert(Boolean(0));) некие типы так же подразумевают перевод из одного типа к другому, например: "123".parseInt();

Пожалуйста.

ЗЫ: А вообще, понятие типов в не типизированном языке - очень размыто.

Comment: Согласен с вами, только что задумался, а какой же тип возвращается у него, хотя раньше как то без этого программировал)

Answer (score 0):

**document.body.style.opacity** вернёт в зависимости от браузера (разные - по-разному), но в основном возвращают дробное число, в нашем случае **0,1 либо 1,0**. Javascript не так глубоко знаю, но могу подсказать функцию, которая вытаскивает из строки целые числа - **parseInt()**.

Answer (score 0):

1. Если в скрипте задается opacity или она прописана напрямую в style="...", то вернет строку. Для преобразования в дробное число используйте parseFloat().
2. А зачем, если все и так приводится? В принципе, есть способы приведения к другим типам:
   **bool**: `!!param`
   **string**: `param+''`
   **int**: `parseInt(param)`
   **float**: `parseFloat(param)`
   **array**: `[param]`